# Ascii range regards binary files?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ascii, binary-data

ive been reading about this topic and didnt get the *specific* info for my question :

(maybe the following is incorrect - but please do correct me)

Every file( text/binary) is saving *BYTES*.

byte is 8 bits hence max value is `2^8-1 = 255` codes.

those 255 codes divides to `2` groups:

```
0..127 : textual chars
128:..255 : special chars.
```

so binary file contains char codes from the whole range : `0..255` ( ascii chars+special chars).

1 ) correct ?

2) NOw , lets say im saving one INT in binary file. ( 4 byte in 32 bit system)

how does the file tells the progem reads it :  its **not** 4 single unrelated bytes **but** an int which `is` 4 bytes ?

Comment: Byte values are not divided into 2 groups. Sure, the ASCII range is up to 127, so higher values are not ASCII, but in many other character sets, all 255 values are text. So you shouldn't think in terms of textual and non-textual chars.

Comment: Just a note: 0..255 is 256 distinct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so binary file contains char codes from the whole range : 0..255 ( ascii chars+special chars).

No, a binary file just contains bytes. Values between 0 and 255. They should only be considered as character *at all* if you decide to ascribe that meaning to them. If it's a binary file (e.g. a JPEG) then you shouldn't do that - a byte 65 in image data isn't logically an 'A' - it's whatever byte 65 means at that point in the file.

(Note that even text files aren't divided into "ASCII characters" and "special characters" - it depends on the encoding. In UTF-16, each code unit takes two bytes regardless of its value. In UTF-8 the number of bytes depends on the character you're trying to represent.)

> how does the file tells the progem reads it : its not 4 single unrelated bytes but an int which is 4 bytes ?

The file doesn't tell the program. The program has to know how to read the file. If you ask Notepad to open a JPEG file, it won't show you an image - it will show you gibberish. Likewise if you try to force an image viewer to open a text file as if it were a JPEG, it will complain that it's broken.

Programs reading data need to understand the structure of the data they're going to read - they have to know what to expect. In some cases the format is quite flexible, like XML: there are well-specified layers, but then the program reads the values with higher-level meaning - elements, attributes etc. In other cases, the format is absolutely precise: first you'll start with a 4 byte integer, then two 2-byte integers or whatever. It depends on the format.

EDIT: To answer your specific (repeated) comment:

> Im Cmd shell....youve written your binary file. I have no clue what did you do there. how am i suppose to know whether to read 4 single bytes or 4 bytes as once ?

Either the program reading the data needs to know the *meaning* of the data or it doesn't. If it's just copying the file from one place to another, it doesn't need to know the meaning of the data. It doesn't matter whether it copies it one byte at a time or all four bytes at once.

If it *does* need to know the meaning of the data, then just knowing that it's a four byte integer doesn't really help much - it would need to know what that integer *meant* to do anything useful with it. So your file written from the command shell... what does it mean? If I don't know what it means, what does it matter whether I know to read one byte at a time or four bytes as an integer?

(As I mentioned above, there's an intermediate option where code can understand structure without meaning, and expose that structure to other code which then imposes meaning - XML is a classic example of that.)

Comment: Im Cmd shell....youve written your binary file. I have no clue what did you do there. how am i suppose to know whether to read 4 single bytes or 4 bytes as once ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You keep copying and pasting that comment. Please *read the replies to it* instead of just asking the same question again and again.

Comment: as ive seen you posted your answer not as a comment , ive moved it under your answer. and deleted from bellow. ( do check).

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You've still got the same comment in the other answer - and I'd replied to the second copy of that comment before you deleted it.

Comment: ok  , maybe you right. i guess ive redirected this question 1 time to him and the second time to you.  :) sorry.

Comment: ive seen somewhere that in binary files , there is a "length prefix" so that in the begining of a block - the size is written and this is how i know how much to read... is it related?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That's *one type of structure* that can be imposed. It's up to whoever designs the data format. XML doesn't use length-prefixing for example, but Google Protocol Buffers does. (I've now edited my answer to give a fuller response to your comment question, btw.)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That's in a different answer, and it's only correct in *some* formats. It's not true for *all* text formats.

Comment: so Length prefixing its only for texts ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: *What* is only for text? Length prefixing? No, that's a general concept which is applied in many places.

Comment: thank you. 10 years in computers and I didnt know that. ( exe reading structure...)

Answer (score 3):

Underlying all files are being stored as bytes, so in a sense what you're saying is correct. However, if you open a file that's intended to be read as binary and try to read it in a text editor, it will look like gibberish.

How does a program know whether to read a file as text or as binary? (ie as special sets of ASCII or other encoded bytes, or just as the underlying bytes with a different representation)?

Well, it doesn't know - it just does what it's told.

In Windows, you open `.txt` files in notepad - notepad expects to be reading text. Try opening a binary file in notepad. It will open, you will see stuff, but it will be rubbish.

If you're writing your own program you can write using `BinaryWriter` and read using `BinaryReader` if you want to store everything as binary. What would happen if you wrote using `BinaryWriter` and read using `StringReader`?

---

To answer your specific example:

```
using (var test = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(@"c:\test.bin", FileMode.Create)))
{
    test.Write(10);
    test.Write("hello world");
}

using (var test = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(@"c:\test.bin", FileMode.Open)))
{
    var out1 = test.ReadInt32();
    var out2 = test.ReadString();

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", out1, out2);
}
```

See how you have to read in the same order that's written? The file doesn't tell you anything.

Now switch the second part around:

```
using (var test = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(@"c:\test.bin", FileMode.Open)))
{
    var out1 = test.ReadString();
    var out2 = test.ReadInt32();

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", out1, out2);
}
```

You'll get gibberish out (if it works at all). Yet there is nothing you can read in the file that will tell you that beforehand. There is no special information there. The program must know what to do based on some out of band information (a specification of some sort).

Comment: i didnt ask any of these questions...`How does a program know whether to read a file as text or as binary` ?? i asked how does the file storage - tells the program who reads it : " listen the next 4 bytes are 1 int and not 4 different unrelated bytes"....

Comment: The file storage doesn't tell the program, the program has first told the byte storage. You must know the order of what you're reading in binary. The only exception is reading 'string text', which is prepended with length since it's variable.

Comment: `143165624` is represented as `0000-1000-1000-1000-1000-1000-1011-1000`  i can read it as 4 bytes :  `0000-1000` `1000-1000` `1000-1000` `1011-1000` but it shoulnt ! it should be read as one !

Comment: @yamen: I agree with the first part of your comment, but your "string text" part is dubious. *Some* formats length-prefix text, but others don't.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, and it's *up to you* to read the file correctly. You need to understand the structure of the data in order to read it correctly.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should specifically be talking about BinaryWriter in the .NET framework.

Comment: @JonSkeet you made me read about this topic in this weekened... regarding the latest question which you answered ...:)

Comment: @JonSkeet `You need to understand the structure of the data ` ??? does windows knows the structure of every exe his running ?

Comment: If you're talking about Windows executing files when you (say) double click on them - Windows uses file extensions and default programs (in general) to decide what program to pass files to in order to read. Those programs decide how to read them. If we're talking about `exe` files specifically, yes Windows does expect a specific structure to know how to load into memory and execute, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/65122

Comment: @yamen **Im Cmd shell....youve written your binary file. I have no clue what did you do there. how am i suppose to know whether to read 4 single bytes or 4 bytes as once ?**

Comment: Windows assumes that an `.exe` file has a certain structure. It doesn't expect the file to tell it what contents it has, it already knows.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, of course Windows knows the file format of every executable file. It couldn't execute it otherwise.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - you don't know. Only the program that wrote it knows. Unless I as the program writer publish the spec, or you as some random person reverse engineers it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You're only meant to read the file if you know what structure to expect - or if you don't care about the structure because (say) you're just uploading it to a web site, or doing something else which just preserves existing structure without understanding it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir If some process has written an integer as 4 bytes, you must need to know that you'll have to read an integer as 4 bytes. There's nothing special in the file that tells the computer it's an integer.

Comment: And if you're downvoting because you don't understand the answer then please reconsider, it's not how this site works.

Comment: The only way a file has to tell a random reader anything about its contents is the file type. If it is `.txt`, that tells the reader its contents are text, etc. Otherwise, the reader needs to know beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

It's all a matter of interpretation. Neither the file nor the system know what's going on in your file, they just see your storage as a *sequence of bytes* that has absolutely no meaning in itself. The same thing happens in your brain when you read a word (you attempt to choose a language to interpret it in, to give the sequence of characters a meaning).

It is the responsibility of your program to *interpret* the data the way you want it, as there is no single valid interpretation. For example, the sequence of bytes `48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 53 6F 6F 68 6A 75 6E` can be interpreted as:

- A string (`Hello Soohjun`)
- A sequence of 12 one-byte characters (`H`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`, , `S`, `o`, `o`, `h`, `j`, `u`, `n`)
- A sequence of 3 unsigned ints followed by a character (1214606444, 1864389487, 1869113973, 110)
- A character followed by a float followed by an unsigned int followed by a float (72, 6.977992E22, 542338927, 4.4287998E24), and so on...

*You* are the one choosing the meaning of those bytes, another program would make a different interpretation of the very same data, much the same a combination of letters has a different interpretation in say, English and French.

PS: By the way, that's the goal of *reverse engineering* file formats: find the *meaning* of each byte.